# Flutter layout (6 container in Columan )

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-nhibernate, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i want to make 6 container in Column and make the container clickable
[like in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxFPv.png)

```
    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Cours et exercices pour S5 LST IETEL"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 150.0,
        width: 150.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 17.8, vertical: 30.5),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            // color: Colors.green,
            color: Hexcolor("#230A59"),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Electronique Analogique",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Hexcolor("#f2f2f2"),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GridView.count` and you can put your object in a class to have flexible code and  you can define `onTap` property for clickable container like code below:

```
class Test1 extends StatelessWidget {
  List<MainObject> list = [
    MainObject(
      onTap: () {/*some actions*/},
    ),
    MainObject(),
    MainObject(),
    MainObject(),
    MainObject(),
    MainObject(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Cours et exercices pour S5 LST IETEL"),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          children: List.generate(list.length, (index) => list[index]),
        ));
  }
}

class MainObject extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  MainObject({this.onTap});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 150.0,
        width: 150.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 17.8, vertical: 30.5),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
// color: Colors.green,
            color: Color(0xff230A59),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Electronique Analogique",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `GridView.count` to help you generate your layout.

**Code sample**

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  MyWidget({this.items = const []});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: <Widget>[
        ...items
            .map<Widget>(
              (e) => Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 17.8, vertical: 30.5),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF230A59),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    e,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFf2f2f2),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
//               fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You simply create a `GridView` with `crossAxisCount` of 2 (so you will have 2 items per row) and then simply generate your widget list in its `children`.

Try the full code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1f8c679c10b9e4d81c5468810f673031).